# Using swfupload with the Playframework and a Mac

Tags: file-upload, playframework, swfupload

I am trying to implement SWFUpload using the Play! framework and a Mac.
When using a Mac I get a 302 error (Upload Error: 302). This seems, I think, to come from the redirect that happens by getting the upload page of the Play! framework (as it is translated from the routes file?).

It works fine on IE on Windows.

I have searched a lot, and read a lot, but haven't found if there is a particular solution. Are there any suggestions on how to implement this, or any suggestions for another simple to implement file uploader (for big field, with progress)?

**EDIT:**

I have tried both Safari and Firefox on my Macbook and both return as status the 302 upload error. I tried again on Windows with IE and it works fine.

The html (stylesheet) code:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title: 'Upload Media File' /}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/swfupload/swfupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/swfupload/swfupload.queue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/swfupload/fileprogress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/swfupload/handlers.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var swfu;

    window.onload = function() {
    var settings = {
    flash_url : "/public/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
    flash9_url : "/public/swfupload/swfupload_fp9.swf",
    upload_url: "doUpload",
    file_post_name: "data",
    post_params: {"article.id" : "${article?.id}"},
    file_size_limit : "1000 MB",
    file_types : "*.*",
    file_types_description : "All Files",
    file_upload_limit : 1,
    file_queue_limit : 0,
    custom_settings : {
    progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress",
    cancelButtonId : "btnCancel"
    },
    debug: false,

    // Button settings
    button_image_url: "/public/swfupload/TestImageNoText_65x29.png",
    button_width: "65",
    button_height: "29",
    button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceHolder",
    button_text: '<span>Start</span>',
    button_text_style: ".theFont { font-size: 16; }",
    button_text_left_padding: 12,
    button_text_top_padding: 3,

    // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
    swfupload_preload_handler : preLoad,
    swfupload_load_failed_handler : loadFailed,
    file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
    file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
    file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
    upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
    upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
    upload_error_handler : uploadError,
    upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
    upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
    queue_complete_handler : queueComplete  // Queue plugin event
    };

    swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);
    };

</script>

<h2 class="title">#{get 'title' /}</h2>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
#{form @index(), id:'uploadForm', enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
<div class="entity">
    <p>This page demonstrates a simple usage of SWFUpload.  It uses the Queue Plugin to simplify uploading or cancelling all queued files.</p>

    <div class="fieldset flash" id="fsUploadProgress">
        <span class="legend">Upload Queue</span>
    </div>
    <div id="divStatus">0 Files Uploaded</div>
    <div>
        <span id="spanButtonPlaceHolder"></span>
        <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel All Uploads" onclick="swfu.cancelQueue();" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 2px; font-size: 8pt; height: 29px;" />
    </div>
</div>
#{/form}
```

The entry in the routes file (the Articles.upload is the screen, the doUpload is called by swfupload):

```
GET     /admin/articles/{id}/upload             Articles.upload
POST    /admin/articles/doUpload                Articles.doUpload
```

**EDIT 2:**
I also tried Uploadify, which returns the same error. Is there anybody who knows a workaround for the Play! framework or an uploader that does work with Play!

Comment: Have you tried on the Mac but with a different browser? What's your code for handling the file upload?

Comment: I added the code of the stylesheet, and also checked firefox on Mac, but no joy (and I do have the lastest Flash PLayer (11.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is html 5 uploader at http://www.uploadify.com which can be downloaded for $5, and it works perfect for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `/admin/articles/{id}/upload` and call `doUpload` without any /path/to/something, you're in the wrong "directory". Might it be that you test Windows locally, but MacOS remotely?

In any case, the problem most probably has nothing to do with the OS, but with something else.

Comment: I have a try with that. I run Windows 'remotely' from Parallels, and test on my Mac locally (localhost). But I have another Mac to check. I will also look at the path. Maybe if I make sure it is exactly the same there is no 302 needed.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, tested with an other mac on the network and another windows machine on the network and still the same problem. The Play! Framework must use a 302 to redirect which the Flash Player on Mac does not support or so.